# Prove that if R is a symmetric relation, so is R^2.

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

Prove that if R is a symmetric relation, so is R^2.
My attempt : The Relation R has (a,b) provided (b,a) is a member of R.
So if I go on to find R^2 it will always have element (a,a) that makes R^2 symmetric.
Am i correct and does this make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $R$ is a symmetric relation on a set $S$, then what you've shown so far is that $(a,a) \in R^2$ for all $a \in S$.

What you have not yet shown is that if $(a,b) \in R^2$ then $(b,a) \in R^2$.

*Hint:* if $(a,b) \in R^2$, then there is a $c \in S$ such that $(a,c)$ and $(c,b) \in R$.

Comment: @ Simon S: I understood the thing you saying. For (a,b) to belong to R^2 R must have (a,c) and (c,b) and for R to be symmetric it must also have (c,a) and (b,c) so that makes (b,a) belong to R^2. 
How to put that mathematically and explain this concept?

Comment: You just said it.